# popen() is successfull for all commands

Tags: c, fopen, popen, fgets

No matter what "cmd" string is passed in popen(), it is never FAILING for me

So fp is never NULL even for random "cmd" string.

```
FILE *fp;
char path[1035];
char cmd = "randomrandomrandom";
fp = popen(cmd, "r");

if (fp == NULL) {
    //Handle Error
    exit(1);
}
while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", path);
}
pclose(fp);
```

Comment: `popen` doesn't care what command you pass to it, or whether the command makes any sense.  It only fails if it can't pass your command on to `execv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`popen` runs an instance of the *shell*. Starting a shell normally succeeds. You need to determine if it has *terminated* successfully. `popen` itself cannot do that, but `pclose` can: it returns the status of the child process (or -1 if another error has occurred).

So in order to verify that the command has been executed successfully, one needs to check return values of both `popen` and `pclose`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I got it

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be behaving as expected:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html

As you can see, popen only fails when its internal `pipe` command fails--the stream cannot be opened. For example, all the file descriptors are in use